# Headphone or mic detection connected via 3.5 mm jack linux

Tags: linux

I have written a small program that informs when any headphone or mic is connected or not.
I provide a file path to identify, is there any way to know through a C program which file path is for mic or headphone?

Here is the program:

```
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = -1;
    char name[256]= {'\0'};
    struct input_event event;

    /*On my system 
        /dev/input/event6 for headphone
        /dev/input/event5 for mic
    */
    if ((fd = open("/dev/input/event6", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        perror("evdev open");
        exit(1);
    }


    if(ioctl(fd, EVIOCGNAME(sizeof(name)), name) < 0) {
        perror("evdev ioctl");
    }

    printf("The device name on path %s is ===  %s\n Now Plug in or Plug out the device\n",
             argv[1],name);


//    while(1)
    {

        read(fd, &event, sizeof(struct input_event));
        printf("Event type is %d\n", event.type);
        printf("Event code is %d\n", event.code);
        printf("Event value is %d\n", event.value);
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Here i need to provide path in open, I want my program should identify the path of the mic or headphone. Is there anyway to do this?
It would be great to have some help.
thanks,

Comment: How did you find out that event5 and event6 were mic and headphone on your system?

Comment: i just run this program by providing one by one path from /dev/input/event0 to event6. and then for event6 "name" prints something like "HDA Intel PCH Headphone".

Comment: What do `EVIOCGPHYS`, `EVIOCGUNIQ`, and `EVIOCGPROP` show for the devices you have?  Maybe you can edit a full table listing them into  your question.

Comment: it prints like EVIOCGPHYS: ALSA, and EVIOCGUNIQ and EVIOCGPROP didnt give anything. But it does not matter much, I just need that the path which i have given in open () needs to be find out by my program.